# simple spreadsheet help! mean mode min max /naming textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making this simple spreadsheet program for a college project and im resiting this because its hard, now all i need to do is name this textboxes like A6,B7 etc its a 26 by 26 app.and i need to do min max mode and median for them. yes i have to only use textboxes and not gridboxes.

i have already done basic sums like + - * /

https://www.codepile.net/pile/ByZ5157D

i have to post it as a copy link as stack says my post is mostly code/ thanks.

No error messages. i expect to have named the textboxes and i tried using linq but it does not work.

I've tried searching everywhere but no help, I've even asked teachers but no help.

Answer (score 0):

**create 26X26 textboxes** and rename you can create an event to each textbox here is the code:

```
private void A1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtShow.text = A1.Name;
}
```

***the code above is for referencing format for individual cells (A1) ***

Comment: kindly use the copy link or inbox me on how to label these textboxes im really confused and need help asap... my deadline is on thursday and i paid for this ...

Comment: please also tell me how to do min max mode and median loops as well check the code out on the codepile link. please? 60 pounds is alot for a resit.smh